# type in vhdl corresponds to c-language: "uint32_t" or "unsigned long"

Tags: vhdl

What's the closet data type in VHDL to the classic c-language data type "uint32_t", example:

```
#include "stdint.h"
void main() {
    uint32_t data = 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

From my understanding, VHDL's "positive" and "natural" types are just subsets of a signed "integer" type and are missing half of the range of c-langauge uint32_t type.

```
architecture sim of testbench is
    --integer range: -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647
    --same as c-language int32_t
    signal a0 :integer  := 1;  

    --integer range: 0 to +2,147,483,647
    --same as c-language int32_t and'ed with 0x7FFFFFFF
    signal a1 :natural  := 1;

    --integer range: 1 to +2,147,483,647
    --same as c-language int32_t and'ed with 0x7FFFFFFF, and 0 thrown away
    signal a2 :positive := 1;

    --integer range: -1 to -2,147,483,648
    --same as c-language int32_t or'ed with 0x80000000, and 0 thrown away
    signal a3 :negative := 1;


    --unsigned integer range: 0 to 4,294,967,295
    --??????  does it exist in VHDL?
    signal a4 :uint32_t 

begin
end architecture;
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you stop comparing HDL with normal programming languages. It will only put your mind and your way of designing HDL totally on the wrong track. For example in HDL you make a variable "as big as it needs to be". You work with 9, 17, 32 or 48 bits. (By the way there are multiple ways of making an unsigned 32 bits integer. I see this first answer arriving already.)

Comment: true, but VHDL still needs to interface with c-language applications that have these data sizes hardwired into the CPU, so its important to know this information.  also, your VHDL simulations will run faster is your stick with sizes that match CPU integer sizes supported by the instruction set.  No sense is wasting a bit just because VHDL doesn't automatically define uint32_t data type.

Comment: The only type which simulates faster is the Verilog 'int' type, being expressly defined for that purpose. All the others will not gain you anything. Just because you use 32 bits does not mean the simulator will map it on an integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity testit is
end entity;

architecture sim of testit is
    subtype uint32_t is unsigned(31 downto 0);

    signal a1 :uint32_t := X"FFFFFFFF";
    signal a2 :uint32_t := X"AFFFFFFF";

    -- Error out of bounds
    --signal a3 :integer := 16#FFFFFFFF;
begin
end architecture;
```

Comment: Actually,  while this is technically closest (and defacto usage),  it will simulate the slowest.  It is based on the 9 state std_logic type,  and is also a signal,  so timing and scheduling is involved.  The closest thing would probably be  `variable uint : unsigned(31 downto 0)` where unsigned type comes from `ieee.numeric_bit`

Comment: Also, vhdl 2019 will require integers to be 64 bit

Comment: Actually, that's even better than a normal VHDL integer if its 9-level logic...that means you can create logic using an integer and not worry about X's getting mixed up with 0's...  better yet, subtype uint64_t is unsigned(63 downto 0);   and subtype int64_t is signed(63 downto 0); not sure why VHDL 2019 is even bothering with integer type...they should just get rid of it and create a "stdint" package that defines all the same integers as c-language header file: #include <stdint> using signed and unsigned instead of built-in integer type... that makes VHDL less annoying in my opinion.

Comment: If you want that,  use verilog.  The point of the integer type is that it faster to simulate and uses far less memory than an array type. It initialises to an actual value,  can be subtyped to any discrete range and is generally what you use as an array index. Because you can range it is easy to detect an out of bounds error.  Signed or unsigned would never do that.  They are of the range 0 to 2^n for unsigned. Basically integer types have a lot of uses that wouldn't work with an array type.